# OpenGL calls segfault when called from OpenMP thread

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, openmp

Let me start by trying to specify what I want to do:

Given a grey scale image, I want to create 256 layers (assuming 8bit images), where each layer is the image thresholded with a grey scale i -- which is also the i'th layer (so, i=0:255). For all of these layers I want to compute various other things which are not very relevant to my problem, but this should explain the structure of my code.

The problem is that I need to execute the code very often, so I want to speed things up as much as possible, using a short amount of time (so, simple speedup tricks only). Therefore I figured I could use the OpenMP library, as I have a quad core, and everything is CPU-based at the moment.

This brings me to the following code, which executes fine (at least, it looks fine :) ):

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,out,tmp,cc)
    for(i=0; i< numLayers; i++){
        cc=new ConnectedComponents(255);
        out = (unsigned int *) malloc(in->dimX()* in->dimY()*sizeof(int));
        tmp = (*in).dupe();
        tmp->threshold((float) i);
        if(!tmp){       printf("Could not allocate enough memory\n");   exit(-1);   }

        cc->connected(tmp->data(),out,tmp->dimX(),tmp->dimY(),std::equal_to<unsigned int>(), true);

        free(out);
        delete tmp;
        delete cc;
    }
```

ConnectedComponents is just some library which implements the 2-pass floodfill, just there for illustration, it is not really part of the problem.

This code finishes fine with 2,3,4,8 threads (didn't test any other number).

So, now the weird part. I wanted to add some visual feedback, helping me to debug. The object `tmp` contains a method called `saveAsTexture()`, which basically does all the work for me, and returns the texture ID. This function works fine single threaded, and also works fine with 2 threads. However, as soon as I go beyond 2 threads, the method causes a segmentation fault.

Even with #pragma omp critical around it (just in case `saveAsTexture()` is not thread-safe), or executing it only once, it still crashes. This is the code I have added to the previous loop:

```
    if(i==100){
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            tmp->saveToTexture();
        }
    }
```

which is only executed once, since `i` is the iterator, and it is a critical section... Still, the code ALWAYS segfaults at the first openGL call (bruteforce tests with printf(), fflush(stdout)).

So, just to make sure I am not leaving out relevant information, here is the `saveAsTexture` function:

```
template <class T> GLuint FIELD<T>::saveToTexture() {
    unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(dimX()*dimY()*3*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(!buf){ printf("Could not allocate memory\n"); exit(-1); }
    float m,M,avg;
    minmax(m,M,avg);
    const float* d = data();
    int j=0;

    for(int i=dimY()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        for(const float *s=d+dimX()*i, *e=s+dimX(); s<e; s++) {
            float r,g,b,v = ((*s)-m)/(M-m);
            v = (v>0)?v:0;
            if (v>M) { r=g=b=1; }
            else { v = (v<1)?v:1; }
            r=g=b=v;
            buf[j++] = (unsigned char)(int)(255*r);
            buf[j++] = (unsigned char)(int)(255*g);
            buf[j++] = (unsigned char)(int)(255*b);
        }
    }

    GLuint texid;
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &texid);
    printf("TextureID: %d\n", texid);
    fflush(stdout);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, dimX(), dimY(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    free(buf);
    return texid;
}
```

It is good to note here that `T` is ALWAYS a float in my program.

So, I do not understand why this program works fine when executed with 1 or 2 threads (executed ~25 times, 100% success), but segfaults when using more threads (executed ~25 times, 0% success). And ALWAYS at the first openGL call (e.g. if I remove glPixelStorei(), it segfaults at glDisable()).
Am I overlooking something really obvious, am I encountering a weird OpenMP bug, or... what is happening?

Comment: I would have said it was because you were accessing the OpenGL context from a different thread than the one it was created on, but you state it works OK with 2 threads.

Comment: Where do you created your GL context?  Where do you make your GL context current?

Answer (score 4):

You can only make OpenGL calls from [one thread at a time](http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html), and the thread has to have the current context active.

Comment: That's not precisely correct.  Better: "An OpenGL context can only be current on one thread at a time."

Answer (score 2):

An OpenGL context can only be used by one thread at a time (limitation imposed by `wglMakeCurrent`/`glxMakeCurrent`).

However, you said you're using layers.  I think you can use different contexts for different layers, with the `WGL_ARB_create_context` extension (I think there's one for linux too) and setting the `WGL_CONTEXT_LAYER_PLANE_ARB` parameter.  Then you could have a different context per thread, and things should work out.

Comment: WGL_ARB_create_context works nicely, but honestly I would rather just glMapbuffer() in the main thread, fill the buffer in another thread, and signal a synchronization primitive. Then unmap the buffer in the main thread and call glTexImage. That will be many times easier to maintain and less error-prone. It won't block the render thread, and that's what counts.

The code does not really look like it would benefit a lot from using 4 threads, it is more or less a memcpy on steroids, so... it will be solely bound by memory bandwidth, and 4 cores will do none faster than one.

Comment: @dm: Yeah probably true.  I was just offering a way to make multi-threading work, but this scenario probably doesn't benefit from it much.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for all the answers! Now I know why it fails I have decided to simply store everything in a big 3D texture (because this was an even easier solution), and just send all the data to the GPU at once. That works fine in this case.